# CheckboxList in ASP.Net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

My application needs to do an HTTP post of a table with checkboxes . On the controller side I will need to traverse the table and perform certain operations for each row that was checked.

The things that I need to do are:

Identify whether a row is checked

Here is my code:

**view :**

```html
@model IEnumerable<LinqToTwitter.User>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page d'accueil";
}
<h2>Twitter</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    </tr>
@foreach (var tweet in Model)
{               
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="rowIDs" type="checkbox" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <img alt="" src="@tweet.ProfileImageUrl" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <strong>@tweet.Name</strong>
            <br />
            Friends: <strong>@tweet.FriendsCount</strong>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**controller :**

```
{.....
    string nextCursor = "-1";

    List<LinqToTwitter.User> result = new List<LinqToTwitter.User>();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextCursor) && nextCursor != "0")
    {
        var followers =
        (from tweet in twitterCtx.User
            where tweet.Type == UserType.Followers &&
            tweet.ID == auth.UserId &&
            tweet.Cursor == nextCursor
            select tweet).ToList();

        result.AddRange(followers);
        nextCursor = followers[0].CursorMovement.Next;
    }
    return View(result);
}
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: For us to help you, you need to post some code on what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is used to help you to solve problems, not solve your problems for you.

Comment: thanks @jacqijvv    here is my code,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post input tags to server, they must be in a form tag. Then your html must be something like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<LinqToTwitter.User>
@{
         ViewBag.Title = "Page d'accueil";
}
<h2>
    Twitter</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var tweet in Model)
        {               
            <tr>
                 <td>
                    <input id="@("chk" + @tweet.ID.ToString())" type="checkbox" name="@("chk" + @tweet.ID.ToString())"  />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src="@tweet.ProfileImageUrl" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong>@tweet.Name</strong>
                    <br />
                    Friends: <strong>@tweet.FriendsCount</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

note how to define form tag by HtmlHelper and define of checkbox to have unique ID.

and your controller code like this:

```
Dictionary<int, bool> isChecked = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

foreach (LinqToTwitter.User item in twitterCtx.User)
{
    if (Request.Form["chk" + item.ID.ToString()] != null && Request.Form["chk" + item.ID.ToString()] == "on")
        isChecked.Add(item.ID, true);
    else
        isChecked.Add(item.ID, false);
}
```

now isChecked Dictionary is contain each item's Id and whether is check or not.